# How to use the wizard to replicate 2 tables into one using a join?

Tags: sql-server-2005, replication

I have one app with one database, and I need to make a replication of some of those tables, and also include one new table which is a join of more than one of those tables.

I tried transaction replication, but the filter for the tables only allows me to modify the 'where' clause.

Anybody can help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd replicate the two tables in question as-is, then [create a view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) on the subscriber to represent your desired join.

Comment: Thanks Joe! I was wondering... if this is the best option I have, then is it better to create the view in the base database and then replicate the view? or is it better to create the view directly in the replication database? I´m thinking it´s better to create it in reporting data base, cause there is no point in creating it in base data base if I won´t be using it there, right? What are your thoughts about this?

Comment: @Ragalante: My opinion would be to create the view only on the reporting database.

Comment: +1 This is definitely the simpler, cleverer solution. @Regalante: You accepted the answer, please upvote is as well. Zero-point accepted answers just make no sense.

Comment: @Paul Sasik: Except as credit towards the "Unsung Hero" badge. I've already got "Tenacious." :-)

Comment: lol. That's right. I gotta tell you. IMO that is the oddest badge choice on SO. Does that mean you're actually aiming for checked answers with zero upvotes? lol. OK. I messed you up here then by upvoting and the asking the OP to upvote as well. Sry.